# Load view first then populate my table view

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 view controllers which I switch with a navigation controller. The second view controller contains a tableview on it which I populate from an xml file when the view is loaded. This makes a little freeze until the second view appears that is populated.

My question is: how to load the view controller with the empty table view then one it appeared, to then start populating the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load and parse the XML data when it changes and keep it ready, rather than presenting an empty table.

Make an array or dictionary as a property of your parent view controller. When your data loads or changes, repopulate the array. When the tableview loads, simply pass in the array or dictionary.

If you really must parse the array *after* presenting the table, then don't begin parsing the XML until the `viewDidAppear`, during which you can parse your data and then call `reloadData` on your table view.